# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'property' of undefined

Tags: angular

my problem is created when i execute the method subscribe, and i don't understand why. 
This is the code and the error generates in console:

```
getInfo(idgestore:number){
    let zonaObs=this._zonaservice.getInfoParks(idgestore);
    zonaObs.subscribe(data=>{
      this.zones=data;
      var citta:string;
      for(var i=0;i<this.zones.length;i++){
        // this.zones[i].citta=null;
        this.location.lat=this.zones[i].latitudine;
        this.location.lng=this.zones[i].longitudine;
        this._zonaservice.getCity(this.location)
        .subscribe((data)=>{
          citta=data;
          })
        console.log(this.zones[i].id);
        var id_zona=this.zones[i].id;
        console.log(id_zona)
        this._tipologiazonaservice.getnumberTotal(id_zona)
        .subscribe((data)=>{
          this.zones[i].numero=data
        })
        console.log(this.zones)
      }
    });

  }
```

Error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'numero' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (allinfopark.component.ts:44)
    at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:238)
    at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
    at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at CatchSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at CatchSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:83)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1226)
```

Comment: Could you also share the service code ? There's no `property` property here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here. You are using the same `i` variable which is [**closure**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) for the

```
.subscribe((data)=>{
    this.zones[i].numero=data
})
```

means that it captures the `i` variable.

This code works `asynchronously`. Means that this `subscribe` will work, after the `getNumberTotal` is ready.

When your code runs first time, `i` is `0`. It reaches to this line and pass this function to another thread (not Javascript thread) to run and continues. When it finishes its call, it waits until your Javascript Thread finishes it's code and after it you get for `i` the value `this.zones.length`. Event loop gets out the callbacks for the subscribes and see there a variable `i` which value is `this.zones[this.zones.length]` and when it tries to call this.zones[this.zones[this.zones.length]], it is undefined. So why you get an error.

Replace your `var i` definition with `let i`. It forces `for loop` for each iteration create it's own `i` variable, each `subscribe` has captures it's own `i`.

Comment: Thanks Suren, I have followed your suggestion and i have resolved the problem.